# Not able to save field of type Map<String, List<String>> using spring data cassandra 2.1.5 RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have a class that has field of type Map<String, List>, I am not able to save that bean in cassandra.
Getting the following error while trying to insert the entity using cassandra Template.
I have created `CassandraMappingContext` and have set the `userTypeResolver` as well.

```
[Exception in request ] [org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot resolve value type for java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>.    
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.lambda$getMapDataType$13(CassandraMappingContext.java:702)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.getDataTypeWithUserTypeFactory(CassandraMappingContext.java:639)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.getMapDataType(CassandraMappingContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.getDataTypeWithUserTypeFactory(CassandraMappingContext.java:639)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.getDataTypeWithUserTypeFactory(CassandraMappingContext.java:587)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.getDataType(CassandraMappingContext.java:547)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getPropertyTargetType(MappingCassandraConverter.java:725)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.lambda$getTargetType$3(MappingCassandraConverter.java:718)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getTargetType(MappingCassandraConverter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:747)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeUpdateFromWrapper(MappingCassandraConverter.java:478)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:383)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:365)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.QueryUtils.createUpdateQuery(QueryUtils.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.update(CassandraTemplate.java:584)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.update(CassandraTemplate.java:571)
```

Looks like the Value in map cannot be anything other than primitive data type.
spring data cassandra version is `2.1.5RELEASE`

but if I directly save this field in db,
and try to run a get api from the code to get the data, I am able to get the field correctly.

I am doing something wrong while saving the data in code?

UPDATE:
Tried adding @CassandraType(type = Name.MAP, typeArguments = {Name.TEXT, Name.LIST }) on top of the field,
But it looks like , we are not allowed to have any thing other than primitive for value in MAP.

Also tried @CassandraType(type = Name.MAP, typeArguments = {Name.TEXT, Name.TEXT }) but then there are some class cast exceptions

Comment: what is the schema of the table?

Comment: the command to create table `create table person (
 id varchar PRIMAY KEY,
 name varchar,
 additionalinfo map<varchar, frozen<list<varchar>>>
);`

Comment: @AlexOtt my java class                                                                                                               `@Data
@Table("person")
public class Person {
 @Id
 private String id;
 private String name;
 private Map<String, Liat<String>> additionalinfo;
}`

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294412/springboot-cassandra-frozen-value-not-recognised - not sure about current status of it. Basically, there should be an annotation that says that value is frozen

Comment: @AlexOtt I don't think Frozen Annotation is the issue here, this looks like some isse with convertors

Comment: @Mahin Any luck with this, I am also facing similar issue with Map of <String, UDT>?